# Get list of countries from Twilio

Tags: java, twilio

Is there a call to get the list of counties that I can send a message to from Twilio using the java helper? If not, what's the REST API call to get the list of countries?

I want to get countries I can send messages to, not necessary the list of countries with available phone numbers. Are they the same thing?

I found this example in the docs. It gets the available countries, but the country code is the apha code. How do I get the numerical country code for sending messages? I want to let the user choose a country, then enter the phone number without having to put in the country code.

```
ResourceSet<AvailablePhoneNumberCountry> availablePhoneNumbers =
    AvailablePhoneNumberCountry.reader()
            .limit(200)
            .read();
```

Answer (score 0):

Twilio can send SMS (one-way) to many countries. In country mobile numbers are only a requirement when [2-way SMS](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/235288367-Receiving-Two-Way-SMS-and-MMS-Messages-with-Twilio) is required (alternatives in that case may be Twilio WhatsApp).

[SMS Guidelines](https://www.twilio.com/guidelines/sms)

[List Countries with Messaging Service](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/api/pricing)

Answer (score 0):

That's correct, seems like you can't get the entire list using the API, you can try GET country by country

```
curl -X GET 'https://pricing.twilio.com/v1/Messaging/Countries/EE' \
-u $TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID:$TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN
```

You can download the list from a CSV.

Comment: Twilio sent me the csv file of countries and their international calling codes.